# How do you ask "How old is it?"

Tags: word-choice, usage

When commenting on a used article for sale, how do you simply ask how old the item is?

Is "它多大了?" Correct?

Answer (score 2):

> Is "它多大了?" Correct?

No. This can be used to ask the age of a pet, but not a used item.

You can use, “这个东西用了多少年了？” “这个东西买了多长时间了？”

Answer (score 1):

> Is "它多大了?" Correct?

No, 多大 does not apply to objects only for human or animals

Depend on the type of article:

For something that is constantly in use

這電腦**用了多少年了/ 多久了**? (how long has this computer been in use)

這電視**用了多少年了/ 多久了**? (how long has this T.V. been in use)

For something last very long and rarely break down:

這自動手錶**有多久歷史了**? (How long is the history of this automatic watch?)

這單反照相機**有多久歷史了**? (How long is the history of this SLR camera?)

Since 自動手錶 and 照相機 are also constantly in use, you can also say "用了多少年了/ 多久了"

~

Depend on how durable you think 自行車 is, you can say 這自行車用了多少年了 (you think it is very easy to break down) or 這自行車有多久歷史了? (you think it lasts a lifetime)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really ask how old something is.

You're buying a second- hand microwave oven:
这台微波炉你用了多久了？

You're buying something you can use to do something:
这个（东西）用了多久了？

You're buying a second-hand garment:
这件衣服穿了多久了？（回答：我只在觐见女王的时候穿过一次。）

You're getting a second-hand boyfriend:
这位男士有多少个前女友？

Answer (score 0):

In Cantonese, you could say "呢個幾耐㗎"?

Comment: Are you really Cantonese?

Comment: Yes.  Is that wrong?

Comment: 你買二手電腦時會問 "呢部電腦幾耐㗎? " 定係  "呢部電腦用咗幾多年? "又或者 "呢部電腦係幾多年前出㗎?"

Comment: 你講買電腦呢個情況應該噉講，但係我唔知OP係想買乜。譬如，想知件衫幾舊款，可以問“呢件幾耐㗎？”

Answer (score 0):

I would say 这东西哪年的？ which means "when is this item produced?"

*用*了多久了 may work. But it manly focus on how often it used. For example, one may answer 我这件衣服只穿过一次，因为尺寸不合身，商家又不给退货

哪年买的 also works. But there is no guarantee that the seller buy it when it brand new.